# how to set a null value for DefultValue of a property

Tags: asp.net

i have 4 properties
like these

```
    public string strLastName { get; set; }
    public string strSpeciality { get; set; }
    public string strProfession { get; set; }
    public string strUserName { get; set; }
    public string strPassword { get; set; }
    public string strRegDate { get; set; }
```

now how can i set NULL Value for strRegDate property?
i don't want use IF statement,
thanks

Comment: `null` is the default value of string as far as I know so you don't need to change anything.

Comment: are you sure its string? or DateTime

Comment: @DanielElliott you can test it with if(strRegDate==null) { }

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and is roughly equivalent to this more explicit code:

```
private string _strLastName = null;  // default(string)

public string strLastName
{
    get { return _strLastName; }
    set {  _strLastName = value; }
}
```

As you can see, the default value already is null.